# WSO2 SCIM User not reflecting on Carbon UI Users list

Tags: wso2, scim, wso2-identity-server

I've WSO2 IS 5.8.0. Email OTP is enabled on my setup.
I've tried to add user using scim as given in the [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/Using+the+SCIM+2.0+REST+APIs#UsingtheSCIM2.0RESTAPIs-POST/CreateUser). As below:

```
curl -v -k --user admin:admin --data '{"schemas":[],"name":{"familyName":"jackson","givenName":"kim"},"userName":"kim","password":"kimwso2","emails":[{"primary":true,"value":"kim.jackson@gmail.com","type":"home"}]}' --header "Content-Type:application/json" https://localhost:9443/scim2/Users
```

I've kept only one entry in `email` array as `primary:true`. The use is added to WSO2 but I can't see it's email address is to be updated which causing an issue while logging in using Email OTP (as It's not able to find email address)

Here is the screenshot of profile details of above user:
[image]

How to update the email as well to the users we create using scim ? 
Also what's the API to update roles for the same while creating user ?

Answer (score 1):

After making some changes into request json body, I'm able to reflect this on CARBON Users Profile UI.

```
curl -v -k --user admin:admin --data '{"schemas":[],"name":{"familyName":"jackson","givenName":"kim"},"userName":"kim","password":"kimwso2","emails":[{"primary":true,"value":"kim.jackson@gmail.com"}]}' --header "Content-Type:application/json" https://localhost:9443/scim2/Users
```

I've removed the key `"type":"home"` from `emails` array & it has reflected as expected.